# Javascript recursive function inside a for loop

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, recursion

```
var f_drum_min = function myself(a){
  alert(a);
  $f_min_node.push(a);
    for (i=0;i<=$m;i++){
      if ($f_leg[i][1]==a){
          myself($f_leg[i][0]);
      }
    }  
};
```

`myself($f_leg[i][0]);` breaks the `for` loop , how can I make it run multiple times in loop?

Comment: `var f_drum_min = function myself(a)` Not seems legit.

Comment: @u_mulder: Actually that is valid JavaScript syntax.  The identifier `myself` will only exist *inside* the function, though.

Comment: @RocketHazmat thanks, now I know more)

Comment: What is $f_leg? What is $m?  It's hard to get a grasp of where it could be going wrong without a bit more info.

Comment: What happens when the for loop "breaks"? Is there an error?

Comment: @u_mulder: They are called "named function expressions": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function :-)

Comment: How does it "break"?  Is there an error in the console?  Won't this be an infinite loop?

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat: it works ,the condition is true several times in loop  but run just first time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function is riddled with bad habits

There's no way for me to improve *this* function because I have no idea what all of those external states do. Nor is it immediately apparent what their data types are.

These are bad habits because there's no possible way to know the *effect* of your function. Its only input is `a`, yet the function depends on `$f_min_node`, `$f_leg`, and `$m`.

- What is the value of those variables at the time you call your function?
- What other functions change those values?
- I assigned `$f_min_node` to some value and then called `f_drum_min`. How was I supposed to know that `$f_min_node` was going to get changed?

Every time you call your function, it's a big surprise what happens as a result. These are the woes of writing non-deterministic ("impure") functions.

> **Until you can fix these problems, recursion in a for-loop the *least* of your concerns**

I have annotated your code with comments here

```
// bad function naming. what??
var f_drum_min = function myself(a){

  // side effect
  alert(a);

  // external state: $f_min_node
  // mutation: $f_min_node
  $f_min_node.push(a);

    // leaked global: i
    // external state: $m
    for (i=0;i<=$m;i++){

      // external state: $f_leg
      // loose equality operator: ==
      if ($f_leg[i][1]==a){
          myself($f_leg[i][0]);
      }
    }  
};
```

I can help you write a deterministic recursive function that uses a linear iterative process though. Most importantly, it doesn't depend on any external state and it never mutates an input.

```
// Number -> Number
var fibonacci = function(n) {
  function iter(i, a, b) {
    if (i === 0)
      return a;
    else
      return iter(i-1, b, a+b);
  }
  return iter(n, 0, 1);
}

fibonacci(6); // 8
```

`for` loops are pretty primitive; Imperative programmers will reach for it almost immediately thinking it's the only way to solve an iteration problem.

I *could've* used a `for` loop in this function, but thinking about the problem in a different way allows me to express it differently and avoid the `for` loop altogether.

Comment: +1 For actually tackling this mess. I took one look and decided it wasn't worth the effort to detail all of this, props to you for doing so.

Comment: @JaredSmith I appreciate the feedback ^.^ If I would've learned how to write better functions 10 years ago, I wonder where I'd be today...

Answer (score 2):

One basic problem with the code, which would cause it to break under almost any circumstances, is that the loop variable `i` is a global, and is thus shared by all recursive invocations of the function.

For example, let's say the function is invoked for the first time. `i` is 0.  Now it recurses, and let's say that the condition in the `if` is never `true`.  At the end of the 2nd call, `i = $m + 1`.  When you return to the first call, because `i` is global, the loop in the first call ends.  I assume this is not what you want.

The fix for this is to declare `i` as local:

```
for (var i=0;i<=$m;i++){
```

This may or may not fix all of your problems (as pointed out in comments, we'd have to see more of your code to identify all possible issues), but it is a critical first step.